# Google test's ambiguous else blocker defeated by GCC 7.1

Tags: c++, gcc

When using Google Test, code like

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    if (argc > 0)
        EXPECT_EQ(argc, argc);
}
```

gets expanded to

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
  if (argc > 0) switch(0) case 0: default:
  //            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    if (argc > 1)
      return 2;
    else
      return 1;

  return 0;
}
```

The `switch(0) case 0: default:` is the expansion of a macro (GTEST_AMBIGUOUS_ELSE_BLOCKER_) which is used to suppress the following warning:

```
prog.cc:3:6: warning: suggest explicit braces to avoid ambiguous 'else' [-Wdangling-else]
   if (argc > 0) switch(0) case 0: default:
      ^
```

However, GCC 7.1 and latest trunk fail to suppress the warning:

https://wandbox.org/permlink/EYZtD8ttDmNI6aeX

whereas clang works as expected:

https://wandbox.org/permlink/zwSPPXtZ1w2SIthX

This looks like a bug in GCC, am I right?

Comment: Why this should be a bug ? For me this is an improvement, this construct is ambiguous. This warning is not mandatory by the standard, maybe you should send an issue to gcc. But I think this is off topic on SO.

Comment: I wouldnt call a false positive for a warning as a bug. With warning its always you who has to make sure that the code is fine, so I'd rather get one warning to many rather than too little

Comment: As a naïve user one might wonder why the ambiguous else warning isn't avoided by actually adding a set of braces. Instead of trying to trick the compiler.

Comment: @BoPersson Because the real code created by gtest is more complicated and allows code like `if (...) EXPECT_EQ(a,b) << "a and b should be equal";` , so the expansion of `EXPECT_EQ` cannot end with a closing brace.

Comment: @Stargateur Why would it be ambiguous? The `else` is inside the `switch`; it cannot possibly belong to the outside `if`.

Comment: @Bulletmagnet - It is never ambiguous to the compiler, because it has a fixed set of rules to follow. However, if you have different numbers of `if`s and `else`s - especially after a macro expansion - what are the odds for the programmer to occasionally get it wrong? And potentially having this kind of errors in test code makes it extra interesting. :-)